# Permission request causes activity recreation on Android Q emulator

Tags: android, android-10.0

I've been testing my app on Android Q and discovered weird behavior that makes app non-functional. I was then able to reproduce it in a new project with minimal code.

The issue is that activity is in an infinite loop of being re-created (onCreate is called over and over). This is triggered by requesting permissions at runtime. This happens even if permissions are already granted and no request UI is shown.

This only happens on Q, not on Pie or Oreo or Marshmallow. I don't know if my code is doing a weird thing, or if it's an OS bug in the current Q emulator image. What do you think? How else can I possibly request permissions on app launch without triggering this bug?

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.a.myapplication">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.a.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.a.myapplication;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.e("Activity", "Activity created!");

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                requestPermissionsOnStartup();
            }
        }, 1500);
    }

    private void requestPermissionsOnStartup() {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                },
                25547);
    }
}
```

And this is what I see in logcat upon launching this app:

```
2019-07-09 11:10:03.234 7454-7454/com.a.myapplication E/Activity: Activity created!
2019-07-09 11:10:03.326 7454-7454/com.a.myapplication E/Activity: Activity created!
2019-07-09 11:10:03.444 7454-7454/com.a.myapplication E/Activity: Activity created!
2019-07-09 11:10:03.577 7454-7454/com.a.myapplication E/Activity: Activity created!
2019-07-09 11:10:03.728 7454-7454/com.a.myapplication E/Activity: Activity created!
2019-07-09 11:10:03.864 7454-7454/com.a.myapplication E/Activity: Activity created!
2019-07-09 11:10:03.987 7454-7454/com.a.myapplication E/Activity: Activity created!
2019-07-09 11:10:04.127 7454-7454/com.a.myapplication E/Activity: Activity created!
2019-07-09 11:10:04.254 7454-7454/com.a.myapplication E/Activity: Activity created!
2019-07-09 11:10:04.371 7454-7454/com.a.myapplication E/Activity: Activity created!
2019-07-09 11:10:04.507 7454-7454/com.a.myapplication E/Activity: Activity created!
```

These are my exact emulator settings:

[image]

Comment: give a try with adding this line in your manifest inside activity - `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`

Comment: is your application trying to access location in background?

If yes then you have to add this permission in manifest 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />`

Comment: @ManojPerumarath: if done without special guards (like a `static boolean` flag to only show the request once), that triggers infinite recursion even on Android 5.0+. That is because `requestPermissions()`triggers `onPause/onResume`, even when no UI is shown (I don't understand why). So if requestPermissions leads to onResume and onResume leads to requestPermissions - you've got infinite recursion.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe No it won't, you need to check the permissions enabled and version > 23 before asking the permissions, which won't cost much i think

Comment: @Al-Amin: `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` seems to work, but I would love to avoid it...

Comment: @ManojPerumarath: it was the first thing I tried in my original large app. It fails horribly. It does what I described. Of note: I already do have `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in that app, which didn't help one bit.

Comment: `android:configChanges` this can cause to trigger oncreate recursively, there by each handler get invoked, since they are on different threads

Comment: @ManojPerumarath: just tried again: `requestPermissions()` in `onResume()`, and no `Handler`; with `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in the manifest. Endless loop of `activity.onCreate()` - `requestPermissions()`.

Comment: For what purpose do you actually need this `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`

Comment: @ManojPerumarath: I don't. It was advised by Al-Amin as a workaround, which in some circumstances does work.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe for me, i had moved the requestpermissions to `onPostResume` then the result was onPostResume being called recursively, then i checked whether the permissions are already enabled , then only i called the method requestpermissions, then the issue was gone

Comment: Get rid of the `Handler`/delay and keep track of configuration changes. See for example https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/tree/v0.4/StorageExplorer and https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/tree/v0.4/LocationForeground, both of which request permissions on first run without a problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare: thanks a lot, another on-point answer as always. SO wouldn't be the same without you. I understand what your example code does (clever use of Bundle, I never considered it because I never has to use this parameter before in any of my projects). But can you please explain what exactly is happening, why is the system re-creating the activity in my case? And it would be great if you posted an actual answer.

Comment: Well, I can't tell you if the problem is tied to your delay or not, which is why I did not post an answer. The need to track configuration changes for permission requests triggered on activity startup has been around since Android 6.0 introduced runtime permissions. Otherwise, if the permission dialog-themed activity is in the foreground, our activity still gets recreated on the configuration change (since it is visible), and we wind up asking for the dialog again.

Comment: @CommonsWare: if I request permissions in `onResume` and without the delay, it also causes endless recreation (so my attempts to use a `static boolean` flag to guard against it are futile).

Comment: Moving my `static boolean` flag into an Application subclass works, but is arguably less neat than the suggested way of using Bundle.

Comment: I have similar issue with requesting ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION, which is odd, because I have it in manifest with fine location. And fine location request works as intended